# jsdoc should be before class or constructor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, jsdoc

Im using a vscode (but should be the same in any code editor), and in the following code, when I hover over `Circle`, it shows me the contents of the jsdoc i've written, but doesn't show them when i hover the variable `radius`. What should I do? Is the only way is to write the jsdoc just above the `constructor`, 'cause that worked in the past?

```js
/**
 * This class represents a circle and can calculate its perimeter and area
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle
 * @constructor
 * @param {number} radius - The radius of the circle.
 */
export default class Circle {
  contructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius
  }

  perimeter = () => {
    return this.radius * 2 * Math.PI
  }

  area = () => {
    return Math.pow(this.radius, 2) * Math.PI
  }
}
```

Comment: What variables do you mean?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the `radius` variable

Comment: You should probably add a type annotation for that property

Comment: its already added, but above the class declaration

Comment: That's a parameter annotation for the constructor. Check the documentation https://jsdoc.app/howto-es2015-classes.html

Comment: i know, that's what i am asking. Is using jsdoc just before the constructor the only way? And it got answered as well, so nothing else is there to discuss here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the only way is to write the jsdoc just above the constructor, 'cause that worked in the past?

Yes.

The [documentation for classes](https://jsdoc.app/howto-es2015-classes.html) shows that the description of the arguments passed to the constructor are specified in documentation on the constructor, not the class.

> ```
> /** Class representing a point. */
> class Point {
>     /**
>      * Create a point.
>      * @param {number} x - The x value.
>      * @param {number} y - The y value.
>      */
>     constructor(x, y) {
>         // ...
>     }
> ```

It also states:

> You don't need to use tags such as @class and @constructor with ES 2015 classes—JSDoc automatically identifies classes and their constructors simply by parsing your code.

`@constructor` is for use when writing traditional constructor functions without the `class` keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I think a very massive library called `TheAlgorithms` has this problem , should I try to create a issue on github?